# How to call a toast message on success callback in class

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a POST API using okhttp library. Everything is working fine except I'm unable to find a way to show a simple toast message on it's success callback. How can I call a toast message to the user so he knows wether data is posted on server or not in the success and failure callbacks?

P.S the code below is in a different class not in a activity class.

This is my code:

```
public DataSource(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mDbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
    mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}



    post(URL, jsonData, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.i("FAILED", "onFailure: Failed to upload data to server");
                //here I want to show toast message
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    Log.i("SUCCESSFUL", "onSuccess: data uploaded");

                    //here I want to show toast message

                } else {
                    Log.i("UN SUCCESSFUL", "onFailure: Failed to upload data to server");
                    //here I want to show toast message
                }
            }
       });
```

Comment: did you getting response in same activity/fragment ?

Comment: did you getting this response in Activity or fragment.

Comment: Pass Activity or Context as final argument to  post(context, URL, jsonData, Callback) method and call Toast.makeText(context, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); inside the Callback

Comment: However, if onResponse() is invoked in another thread other than UI thread pass activity and call runOnUIThread not to get an exception

Comment: And one final thing is use WeakReference with Activity if your app is rotatable to prevent leaks after recreation of Activity.

Comment: @Thracian, I tried passing context in the toast message but it gives me the following error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: That's because onResponse() is called from another thread. use Activity and activity.runOnUIThread() to not get that exception also mind WeakReference and leaking if your app is rotatable

Comment: Or better use Handler as posted answers below. But it requires a bit work to send message from POST API thread and handleMessage on UI thread

Comment: Handler or Activity both are prone to leak if you don't use them without checking life cycle of your app. Rotating when an Activity is attached to a class causes it not be cleared and causes your app to leak memory as much as your Activity and all of it's views consume. And every rotation causes another leak which can make your app unusable or cause OutOfMemoryException. Not only use an answer, also learn how to use it well.

Comment: showing toast have so many way without any error. if getting response in same activity than pass current context, if you getting response in another thread than show toast inside runOnUIThread.

Comment: I don't know why people down casting vote?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every app has its own special thread that runs UI objects such as View objects; this thread is called the UI thread. Only objects running on the UI thread have access to other objects on that thread. Because tasks that you run on a thread from a thread pool aren't running on your UI thread, they don't have access to UI objects. To move data from a background thread to the UI thread, use a Handler that's running on the UI thread or can use android implementation for the same as shown here.

**- Case 1**

```
 MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            void run() {
               Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                    "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            });
```

**- Case 2**

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                    "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Had it been Main thread you would have used it directly like

```
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                    "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

This callback is an asynchronous function, and you can change View just in UI-thread, so `Handler` will be helpd for you.

```
    ....
    private final static int MSG_SUCCESS = 0x0001;
    private final static int MSG_FAIL = 0x0002;
    private Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what){
              case MSG_SUCCESS:
                 //Toast success
                  break;
              case MSG_FAIL:
                 //Toast fail
                  break;
              default:
                  break;
            }
        }
    };

    ......
    ......

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
              Log.i("SUCCESSFUL", "onSuccess: data uploaded");
              handler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_SUCCESS);
           } else {
             Log.i("UN SUCCESSFUL", "onFailure: Failed to upload data to server");
              handler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_FAIL);
            }
     ......
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()

Because you're calling it from a worker thread. You need to call `Toast.makeText()` (and most other functions dealing with the UI) from within the main thread. You could use a handler,

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {    
                    Log.i("SUCCESSFUL", "onSuccess: data uploaded");

                    context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SUCCESSFUL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                  });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
TaskActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        void run() {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(TaskActivity.this,
                "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just send the context of your activity while calling this method:

```
void methodName(Context c){

 post(URL, jsonData, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    Log.i("FAILED", "onFailure: Failed to upload data to server");
                    //here I want to show toast message
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        Log.i("SUCCESSFUL", "onSuccess: data uploaded");
                       Toast.makeText(c,"message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //here I want to show toast message

                    } else {
                        Log.i("UN SUCCESSFUL", "onFailure: Failed to upload data to server");
                        //here I want to show toast message
                    }
                }
});
}
```

Comment: I've tried the same thing but it gives me the following error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Activity**

```
post(URL, jsonData, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        Log.i("FAILED", "onFailure: Failed to upload data to server");
                        //here I want to show toast message
                        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                            Log.i("SUCCESSFUL", "onSuccess: data uploaded");

                            //here I want to show toast message
                            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            Log.i("UN SUCCESSFUL", "onFailure: Failed to upload data to server");
                            //here I want to show toast message
                            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
   });
```

**Fragment**

```
post(URL, jsonData, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        Log.i("FAILED", "onFailure: Failed to upload data to server");
                        //here I want to show toast message
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                            Log.i("SUCCESSFUL", "onSuccess: data uploaded");

                            //here I want to show toast message
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            Log.i("UN SUCCESSFUL", "onFailure: Failed to upload data to server");
                            //here I want to show toast message
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
   });
```

**Edit**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm not calling it inside an activity or fragment. I'm trying to call it in a class, a non UI thread

Comment: @3iL then you can use context of this class.

Comment: I am using the context but it gives the following error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: @3iL Please Add more snippet of in your class.

Comment: @3iL Welcome, Happy to help you.