# How to connect to a 000webhost database?

Tags: android

I design a sign up screen in android studio and I connect it to the 000webhost database through php. I made database in 000webhost and also upload the php file on it. But the problem is when i pressed Register button in my app it crashes. Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

```
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String REG_API = "https://urkk.000webhostapp.com/AndroidAPI/registerUser.php";
    EditText editUsername, editEmail, editPassword, editContact;
    RadioButton rmale, rfemale;
    Button btnReg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        editUsername = findViewById(R.id.editUsername_ID);
        editEmail = findViewById(R.id.editUserEmail_ID);
        editPassword = findViewById(R.id.editUserPassword);
        editContact = findViewById(R.id.editUserContact);
        rmale = findViewById(R.id.radiobtnMale);
        rfemale = findViewById(R.id.radiobtnFemale);
        btnReg = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister_ID);

        btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = editUsername.getText().toString();
                String email = editEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = editPassword.getText().toString();
                String contact = editContact.getText().toString();
                String gender = null;
                if (rmale.isChecked())
                    gender = "Male";
                if (rfemale.isChecked())
                    gender = "Female";

                register(name, email, password, contact, gender);
            }
        });
    }

    public void register(final String strname, final String stremail, final String strpassword, final String strcontact, final String strgender) {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REG_API, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                if (response.trim().equals("User Registered")) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("userName", strname);
                map.put("userEmail", stremail);
                map.put("userPassword", strpassword);
                map.put("userContact", strcontact);
                map.put("userGender", strgender);

                return map;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Php code:

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','id12762759_batman','imbatman','id12762759_users_db');

        $Name = $_POST['userName'];
        $Email = $_POST['userEmail'];
        $Password = $_POST['userPassword'];
        $Contact = $_POST['userContact'];
        $Gender = $_POST['userGender'];

        $q = "insert into tbl_users values ('','$Name','$Email','$Password','$Contact','$Gender')";

        $check = mysqli_query($conn,$q);

        if($check){
            echo 'User Registered';

        }
        else{
            echo 'Registration Failed';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'No Response';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're touching in UI elements from another thread..

> Every app has its own special thread that runs UI objects such as View
>   objects; this thread is called the UI thread. Only objects running on
>   the UI thread have access to other objects on that thread. Because
>   tasks that you run on a thread from a thread pool aren't running on
>   your UI thread, they don't have access to UI objects. To move data
>   from a background thread to the UI thread, use a Handler that's
>   running on the UI thread or can use android implementation for the
>   same as shown here.

Solution is posting `new Runnable()` to the `MainLooper` this will ensure your codes get excuted in main/UI thread.

In your `onResponse()`:

```
if (response.trim().equals("User Registered")) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } else {

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

and in `onErrorResponse()`:

```
@Override
        public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error){
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Or you can use `runOnUiThread()`:

```
 MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            void run() {
               Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                    "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            });
```

See this: [How to call a toast message on success callback in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416459/how-to-call-a-toast-message-on-success-callback-in-class/48416761)

Comment: Thankyou bro app is working.But i am getting registration failed error and mysqli error.

Comment: I am getting Registration Failed when i clicked on Register Button.

Comment: Can you `Log` your response and post that log?

Comment: I am getting socket Exception on emulator and Failed Toast on my mobile phone.

Comment: Looks like the link you’ve provided, is deleted.. (https://urkk.000webhostapp.com/AndroidAPI/registerUser.php) 404